# Problem with locks while moving table to different schema in postgres

Tags: postgresql, locking

I would like to change schema of few tables in my Postgres DB. Problem is that all the time there are long running queries and as I understand schema change needs exclusive lock.

Question is how can I do it? Of course I can kill all existing queries and try to do schema rename (move table to different schema) but there is a huge chance that in the meantime new queries will appear.

Thanks for help!

Comment: "*I understand schema change needs exclusive lock."* - correct. You will have to block new connections until that change is through (which only takes a few seconds, as it is only a "rename" not a real physical move)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- run `SELECT pg_backend_pid()` before running the `ALTER TABLE`
- start the `ALTER TABLE` statement
- in a second database session, run `SELECT pg_blocking_pids(12345)`, where 12345 is the result from the first query
- cancel all the blocking transactions found with the previous query with `SELECT pg_cancel_backend(23456)`